# What is the closest RPG analogue to the newest version of the Mechwarrior RPG?

Tags: battletech, mechwarrior-4e

What is the closest RPG analogue to the newest version of the Mechwarrior RPG?

I played the second and third versions of the mechwarrior rpg, but am unfamiliar with the new Classic BattleTech RPG.

Comment: Uhhh... you mean table-top analogue to computer game?

Comment: @Tobiasopdenbrouw No, Battletech was a tabletop before Mechwarrior existed.  They then created the Mechwarrior tabletop RPG where you role played a mechwarrior.

Comment: I just didn't get your question at first read and thought the question would need clarification for all readers. Now, however, I do get it, but I find myself unable to answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Battlecorps product page](http://battlecorps.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=1771) answers the question:

> *Important Notice: Classic BattleTech RPG is a fourth printing of MechWarrior, Third Edition, with only the cover image and title of the book changing. No other changes have been made to the text.*

Answer (score 4):

The 4th Edition of Mechwarrior is entitled *A Time of War*. A constantly updated Beta version was available as a pdf for quite some time before the print version of the game was launched in hardcover late in 2010.

A Time of War replaces previous editions, and is the first to integrate nearly seamlessly with Battletech. It has several things in common with the 3rd Edition, renamed *The Classic Battletech RPG*, but is quite different mechanically.

More information can be found at the Catalyst website for [Battletech](http://www.classicbattletech.com). In a nutshell, the system uses  exploding 2D6 with modifiers versus set target numbers for task resolution, and provides clear rules for scaling mech combat down to the infantry level. Character options and the life paths and point-buy options to build them are quite broad and definitely continue the 3rd Edition's emphasis on providing options that do not necessarily revolve around 'mechs.

The RPG assumes a game set in 3076. The core rules do not provide information for other periods in the continuity. Expansions are addressing this bit by bit, although past experience with the Battletech Universe is often enough to deal with questions arising from using different eras.

The line is well-supported with releases, and quick responses on the Catalyst Battletech forum.

Answer (score 0):

As clarification: "A Time of War" is the title for the fourth edition of the Mechwarrior RPG which should be coming out soon.